# Get the original property name from a method parameter

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, parameters

How can I get the name of the original property name which is passed as a parameter to a method?

```
class TestA
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }

        public TestA()
        {
            Foo = "Bar";

            TestB.RegisterString(Foo);
        }
    }

    class TestB
    {
        public static void RegisterString(string inputString)
        {
            // Here I want to receive the property name that was used
            // to assign the parameter input string
            // I want to get the property name "Foo"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not possible. Why do you need it?

Comment: I wanted to implement some automated registering for commands with the same name. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an argument with the `nameof` keyword. Not sure why you would want that anyway:

```
TestB.RegisterString(Foo, nameof(Foo));
```

This will pass in `"Foo"` as the second argument. There is no way to automate this, so you don't need to call `nameof` yourself, which makes doing this quite useless.

If you would call this from the `Foo` property, you could use the `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, which will put in the caller's name. The compiler will set the correct value, so you don't have to supply this yourself in the calling method.

```
public static void RegisterString( string inputString
                                 , [CallerMemberName] string caller = null
                                 )
{
    // use caller here
}
```

That makes more sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. An Attribute would be the cleaner solution for this?

Comment: Yes, but you need to put that code in `Foo`. Not sure if that is what you want to, but it is better from my point of view.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)-keyword is new in VS 2015(C#6)